# Keep getting SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Movie' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm working on a program that I take an excel file to a SQL database. I'm using EPPlus -Version 4.5.2.1. I keep getting errors when I import excel file Movie. SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Movie' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
**WebApplication14.Controllers.HomeController.Import(IFormFile file) in HomeController.cs
+
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();**

The HomeController Code:

```
namespace WebApplication14.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
        public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }
        public async Task<List<Movie>> Import(IFormFile file)
        {
            var list = new List<Movie>();
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
                {

                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
                    var rowcount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
                    var colcount = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;

                    for (int row = 2; row < rowcount; row++)
                    {
                        list.Add(new Movie
                        {
                            Id = int.Parse(worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value.ToString().Trim()),
                            Title = worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value.ToString().Trim(),
                            Genre = worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value.ToString().Trim()
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            //SaveDataToDb(list);
            _dbContext.Movie.AddRange(list);
            await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MovieList-1].[dbo].[Movie] ON");
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MovieList-1].[dbo].[Movie] OFF");

            return list;


        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Model Movie

```
namespace WebApplication14.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DbContext Code

```
namespace WebApplication14.Models
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Movie> Movie { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Migration Code

```
public partial class MoviesToDb : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Movie",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Title = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Genre = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Movie", x => x.Id);
                });
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Movie");
        }
    }
}
```

Startup Code

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My AppSettings.Json ConnectionString

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MovieList-1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
```

View/Home/Index

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
    <div class="container">
        <form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Import" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" />
            <button type="submit">Import From Excel</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: EF will open and close the connection after each operation by default.  If you open the connection explicitly it will remain open for the duration of the DbContext.

Comment: Should I remove await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MovieList-1].[dbo].[Movie] OFF");? Or do I need to set something up in the ApplicationDbContext?

Comment: I know there  is already and answer, but I think you should tell us, or consider, whether you really need to insert those IDs. Because if they contain no identity information, you should just not set them and allow IDs to be generated. But if you know that all of these IDs are existing entities in the database, then actually you shouldn't use `Add()`; you should use `_dbContext.Entry(movie).State = EntityState.Modified` instead. This attaches the entity and makes sure that all properties will be written to db.

Answer (score 2):

EF will open and close the connection after each operation by default. This causes the SqlConnection to be returned to the Connection Pool, and its state is cleared, including dropping temp tables, and resetting session-level SET setting, each time it's fetched from the pool.

If you explicitly open the DbContext's connection (or start a transaction), the IDENTITY_INSERT setting should still be in effect when you call SaveChanges():

```
    _dbContext.Database.OpenConnection();
    _dbContext.Movie.AddRange(list);
    await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MovieList-1].[dbo].[Movie] ON");
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MovieList-1].[dbo].[Movie] OFF");
```

Comment: Thanks Ill try that right now! Let you know what happens

Comment: I keep getting an error under Connection in  _dbContext.Database.Connection.Open(); do I need to install anything in NuGet PM?

Comment: NVM the code working I think they changed the Connection.Open() to OpenConnection() and now its working also I forgot to connect SQL Server Object Explore -> Add SQL Server lol

Comment: That's EF Core vs EF6.